# Search data using Elasticsearch and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to search data from elastic search using angularjs 1.6.4 where the steps are.
 1. npm install elasticsearch
 2. written the code in controller given below. 
 but in console.log() given error 'required' is undefined. Is it inject problem ?

Code:

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

const hostname = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
const password = 'password';
const host = `http://user:${password}@${hostname}/elasticsearch`;

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: host,
    log: 'trace',
    header:
        {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }
});

client.ping({
    // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
    requestTimeout: 1000
}, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
        console.log('All is well');
    }
});

client.search({
    index: 'myindex',
    q: 'title:test'
}, function callback(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        client.create({
            index: 'myindex',
            type: 'mytype',
            id: '1',
            body: {
                title: 'test',
                tags: ['y', 'z'],
                published: true,
                published_at: '2013-01-01',
                counter: 1
            }
        }, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                console.trace(error);
            } else {
                console.log(`Created myindex: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(`Found myindex: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are getting "require is not defined" then this errors occurs when you are executing require() this on Browser,as this is specific feature of nodejs(Server Side).You will have to browserify this.

Comment: Hi ,
The issue is solved. actually this is a NODE js code and in Firebase NODE js is back end to use firebase function and I used firebase function while storing data in firebase using onCreate event to store query data stored in Elastic search then to write again firebases event to search data from Elastic search and show using Angularjs then HTML page.